# Git - Will "GitHub Importer" delete your old repository?

Tags: git, github, enterprise, github-for-windows

I want to use the "GitHub Importer" tool (https://help.github.com/articles/importing-source-code-to-github/) to copy a private repository from a GitHub Enterprise server unto my personal account on Github.com but does anybody know if this will delete the old repository on the GitHub Enterprise server? I don't want it to. Also I don't want my newly copied repo on my personal account to affect the repo on the GitHub Enterprise server in any way. Will it?

Comment: your best bet for a question like this is to ask github directly; https://github.com/contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will simply create a copy on your account. The original (enterprise) will be kept the same and no changes from the copy will be reflected on the enterprise